# Best practice for designing flows that require recursion and same-record updates

Tags: visual-workflow, after-trigger, bestpractice, recursion, before-save-flow

I'd like some inputs on the current best practice for building Flow automation which a) needs to update the same triggering record but only after an action (like sending an email) that isn't available in Before-Save flows, and b) will require re-running the flow (i.e. intentional recursion) from top to bottom again.

**Quick business context:** We track Applications to programs, that go through various stages. We have a flow that runs when an Application is updated and the first thing it does is check the Stage the Application is in and then run any logic applicable to that Stage.

#### Question 1:

Best practice says that if you are updating the same record in a transaction, that update should be done in a Before-Save (Fast Field Updates) Flow. However, if you need to FIRST do something like send an email, or publish a platform event, and only update the triggering record AFTER one of those actions... What do you do? Before-Save Flows are super limited in their actions, so I can't send an email in one and then update the record. Is this just a scenario in which the record update can/should go in an After-Save flow rather than a Before-Save flow?

#### Question 2:

If, after updating the same triggering record in an After-Save flow, you now need to re-evaluate the entire Flow from the beginning (i.e. cause intentional recursion), what is the best way to do that? Based on [the Order of Execution doc](https://architect.salesforce.com/1/asset/immutable/s/e6cf2ac/assets/images/Salesforce-Order-Of-Execution-Diagram.png)s, Flows do not have recursion enabled, so if you update the same record that triggered the flow, it will NOT re-run the Flow. The only way I can think of forcing recursion is by using a Flow **connector at the end** which points it back up to the top of the flow to re-evaluate the very first decision node (which checks the Application Stage, which may now have been updated). **Is that acceptable?**

#### Question 3:

If our Application process has 10 different stages, each with its own pieces of logic that may need to run (some stages being more complex/lengthy than others), is there any obvious benefit to breaking this into 10 different record-triggered flows? I realise that may be a bit "neater" in some ways, but then if an Applicant got to Stage 5 and we needed to kick the Applicant back to Stage 3 AND re-run the Stage 3 Flow, how would we do that? If all stages were contained in 1 Flow, we could use a connector element to point back to the Stage 3 branch of the Flow, but if we split the logic into 1 Flow per stage, I can't see how we would ever be able to go backwards or force some recursion. I suppose this question goes hand-in-hand with the previous one about the right way to intentionally cause recursion of Flow.

**Thanks in advance! Looking forward to learning some design best practices here.**